# "stdin: is not a tty" message from scp

Tags: scp, tty, stdin

I got this message when I copy file using scp to CentOS server `"stdin: is not a tty"`. What it means and how I make it go away? The transfer is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because the `/etc/bashrc` script is trying to run stty, and indeed, stdin is not a tty.

You should make sure your login script exits early when it is being used in a non-interactive manner.

In csh syntax this is usually done by adding something like this to your login script (prior to commands like `stty` that are only useful for interactive sessions):

```
if ( ! $?USER || "$prompt" == "" || ! $?term ) then
    exit
endif
```

The same thing can be accomplished in bash by adding the following at the beginning of `.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```